# How to change the position of Related Product Block in Magento 1.9.3.6?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, ce-1.9.0.1, magento1.9.3

I am using magento 1.9.3.6 version, RWD theme. I want to move related product block before displaying upsell products. How can I achieve this?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding below code in local.xml or Catalog.xml of your theme layout files (app/design/frontend/{{your_package}}/{{Your_Theme}}/layout).

```
<catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="right">
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.product.related</name></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" before="product.info.upsell" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
        </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

In case its not showing after layout updates, add below code to

app/design/frontend/{{your_package}}/{{Your_Theme}}/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('catalog.product.related'); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, code worked but related products are showing below Upsell products and products are also showing in vertical list. I want them to set horizontal similar like upsell products list

Comment: answer is updated, please update the xml in your xml file. The text 'after="-" ' is updated to 'before="product.info.upsell"'.